# Semi-Aquatic Ants

Tags: evolution, fauna, insects

Is it plausible for a species of ant that inhabits a mangrove-like marine environment to have their abdomen evolve into a tail-like appendage for swimming to move from tree to tree to forage?

Comment: Tangentially relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1610/

Comment: How will they follow [pheromone trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_pheromone) through water?

Comment: I honestly hadn't even considered that @user535733

Comment: tail like might be tricky, that would require a complete redesign of the abdomen, bristly legs that work like paddles are far far more likely, you may want to look at boatsman bugs for ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You want bubble bees.**

There exist aquatic hymenopterans!  I had never heard of them until I read for this question so thank you!  Hymenoptera is the order to which ants as well as bees and wasps belong.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-8259-7_51

> All aquatic Hymenoptera are parasitoids. Many species have relatively
>   dense pubescence to trap air and elongate, tarsal claws to grip the
>   substrate, when underwater. Most species are known from the Holarctic
>   and Oriental regions, but this is likely an artefact caused by lack of
>   knowledge of other regions of the world. Aquatic behaviour has evolved
>   independently at least 50 times within the order.

Dense pubescence means they are hairy, which is the method diving spiders use to carry a bubble of air around with them.  Bees are plenty hairy already and I bet they could pull this off.  Breathing thru a tail snorkel is done by [rat-tailed maggots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat-tailed_maggot) which are fly larvae so if you really wanted to do that you could have your bees with rat tails.  But the maggots are not super mobile I do not think - mobile things like spiders, wasps, beetles and your bees will probably just surface to recharge the bubble.

I found this video of [Prestwichia aquatica](https://translate.google.com/translate?&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrestwichia+aquatica&sl=ru&tl=en&prev=_t&hl=en) and I think I can see the bubbles trapped under the wing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzMhgKp-ylY
[image: Prestwichia aquatica]

For such a cool animal I was surprised to find nothing on the pop biology sites!  Even the Wikipedia article is translated from the Russian.  National Geographic if you are watching, aquatic wasps would be a fine topic.

Answer (score 1):

No evolution needed, in the Ants View of the World an individual can be sacrificed and used as part of a bridge.  Clusters of ants bridge over or float over, get on a clump of mangrove, and strip it bare.  When no more resources on the dry, they start extending out.  Tides, winds, fish splashing, etc. break off clumps that then float a few more feet and hit another clump of mangrove, or perhaps a bridge out exploring gets lucky.  Plenty of youtube vids of clumps of ants floating, forming bridges across small spans of still water, etc.

Comment: This does not work as standard procedure, if done every day this will quickly leave you with no ants.